# Selenium- After click a link,IE opens two windows instead of one window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm working on the secured web application. When I click link within frame, it opened another single window where information to be filled.But when I execute this scenario in selenium, it click the link within frame and system display two windows where window1 shows Blank page with title as "Blank Page- window internet explorer' and window2 shows website security certificate with no title.

When I'm doing manually, it showing single window but during automation, it shows two windows.

Note: Application support only IE10.

script:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","./tools/IEDriverServer_32.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
    driver.get(url);
         driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

Login the application and next step to click link

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@id='maintable']//a").click();

Please help me on this.

[image]

Comment: Please share the HTML of your page.

Comment: Use windows handlers to switch on new tab.

Comment: My issue is it throw two windows instead of a window not on switch of windows.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same issue in IE 10..The issue appears to be resolved when I am setting "nativeEvents" to true using the DesiredCapabilities Class. You may try the same and let us know if it also works for you. Please find code segments for your reference:

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

The 2nd Line seems to do the trick.

Comment: This did not work for me. I am facing exactly same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked

Modifying the registry  value , TabProcGrowth to 0 solved the issue-

Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
TabProcGrowth (right-click) → Modify… → Value data: 0

Answer (score -1):

```
which version of selenium jar are you using. Try below code... 

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","./tools/IEDriverServer_32.exe"); WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();   
driver.get(url); driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()‌​"); 

if this not works.... last option, please Reinstall IE and problme will be fixed.
```

Comment: I'm using Lync which is offical communicator. Is there any impact based on this software.? I checked control panel, which is not there.

Comment: which version of selenium jar are you using.  Try below code... 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","./tools/IEDriverServer_32.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get(url);
         driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()"); if this not works.... last option, please Reinstall IE and problme will be fixed.